# How can I convert an .mkv file to .mp4 and keep the subtitles?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion, subtitle

I've been trying to convert an .mkv file into .mp4.
With VLC the subtitles got lost.

Then I've been trying `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -codec copy video.mp4
```

The conversion has been very fast, the file size has been almost the same, but the subtitles were lost, too.

Answer (score 1):

The subtitles are lost, since mp4 containers cannot hold subtitles.

Easiest way to copy all into a "mov" container, which is very close to the mp4 container:

`ffmepg -i 01.mkv -acodec copy -vcodec copy -scodec copy output.m4v`

Answer (score 0):

I've found [an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1273770/596513) by [Mokubai](https://superuser.com/users/19943/mokubai) on [this question on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1273764/using-ffmpeg-on-how-do-i-copy-the-video-and-multiple-subtitle-streams-in-an-mkv)

> I believe you need to specify the mapping of the audio and subtitle streams to ensure that *all* of them are copied through rather than the first. To do so you need to add `-map 0:a? -map 0:s? -map 0:v` before your `-c:v`
>
> This should make your command
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i "01.mkv" -map 0:a? -map 0:s? -map 0:v -c:v copy -c:a ac3 -c:s copy "test.mkv"
> ```
>
> The map command is used to tell it that you definitely want those things to be pulled through to the output. `-map 0:a:1` would specify only to copy audio stream number 1, while `-map 0:a?` should effectively wildcard it and copy them all.

It worked, but the .mp4 file is larger.

Comment: How much larger? Double? You are transcoding the audio. That could cause some increase.

Answer (score 0):

As a GUI for `ffmpeg` there is this tool: [dmMediaConverter](https://sites.google.com/site/dmsimpleapps/dmMediaConverter?authuser=0).

With mkv internal subtitles though, I had to edit the subtitle codec and change to `mov_tex`.

[image]